# forward declaration and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, forward-declaration

I have the following code.

Handler.h

```
class FwdClass;

class Handler {
 public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<FwdClass>
  getFwdClass() noexcept {
    return nullptr;
  }
  virtual ~Handler() {
  }
};
```

DerivedHandler.h

```
#include "Handler.h"

class DerivedHandler: public Handler {
 explicit DerivedHandler() { // error here
 }
  getFwdClass () noexcept override {
    return std::unique_ptr<FwdClass>(std::move(p));
  }
 std::unique_ptr<FwdClass> p;
}
```

```
**error:** invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'FwdClass'
        static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
```

and also:

```
note: in instantiation of member function 'std::default_delete<FwdClass>::operator()' requested here
          get_deleter()(std::move(__ptr));
```

Why am I seeing these errors? Best way to fix this kind of a thing would be much appreciated.

I cannot include FwdClass.h because FwdClass.cpp needs to include DerivedHandler.h and to avoid circular dependency, I created interface class Handler.h and did forward decl. It was working well with raw pointer, but barfs with unique_ptr.

edit: (more details)

FwdClass.cpp implementation includes DerivedHandler.h, so I cannot include FwdClass header DerivedHandler.h as it leads to circular dependency.
That is why, I was doing the forward declaration.
Forward declaration works fine with raw ptrs, but not with unique ptrs.

I made a DerivedHandler.cpp and included FwdClass.h but that still does not help.

I don't think this is a repeat question, specially not with the circular dependency nuance.

Comment: Moving the definition of your destructor of `DerivedHandler` into a cpp file might help, you probably need to move the definitions of `getFwdClass` out of line too

Comment: @AlanBirtles getFwdClass out of line meaning in DerivedHandler.cpp?

Comment: yes, or anywhere that `FwdClass` is not incomplete