# Circular dependency and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, forward-declaration

I have the following code.

Handler.h

```
class FwdClass;

class Handler {
 public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<FwdClass> getFwdClass() noexcept {
    return nullptr;
  }
  virtual ~Handler() {
  }
};
```

DerivedHandler.h

```
#include "Handler.h"

class DerivedHandler: public Handler {
 explicit DerivedHandler() { // error here
 }
  std::unique_ptr<FwdClass> getFwdClass () noexcept override {
    return std::unique_ptr<FwdClass>(std::move(p));
  }
 std::unique_ptr<FwdClass> p;
}
```

I see the following compile errors:

```
**error:** invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'FwdClass'
        static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
and also:
```

```
note: in instantiation of member function 'std::default_delete<FwdClass>::operator()' requested here
          get_deleter()(std::move(__ptr));
```

How can I fix these?  I have tried to make a DerivedHandler.cpp file with getFwdClass/ default destructor defined and included FwdClass.h but that does not help.

(more details)

FwdClass.cpp implementation includes DerivedHandler.h, so I cannot include FwdClass header DerivedHandler.h as it leads to circular dependency. That is why, I was doing the forward declaration and the interface class Handler.h. Forward declaration works fine with raw ptrs, but not with unique ptrs.

I don't think this is a duplicate question, specially not with the circular dependency nuance.

Comment: Moving the implementations to .cc file will help. The code snippet can't come, the overridden method returns  what?

Comment: Does forward declaration supports std::move ?

Comment: How does this differ from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986179/forward-declaration-and-unique-ptr)?